# WordPress makes 404 error when going to domain folder

Tags: directory

I have site steamshopsrbija.com and when I navigate to new WP installation on steamshopsrbija.com/v2 (it is new folder called v2)it makes like it does not exist. So WP thinks it is page ?

How to fix that problem?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Your other CMS is saying it doesn't exist. Did you go through the full WP setup process of creating a database, then installing WP?

Comment: @UrosAleksic: as I see, you've fixed it. Now in v2 folder you have another WordPress installation ( presumably version 2 of your website ), therefore, something to execute. It would be nice to add a comment saying: Thank you. It's fixed now.", so people stop trying to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing subfolder permission from 750 to 755.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone will to help. After a long search I found solution! **Here is help for others if need:**

Im quote:

To exclude the subfolders from the WordPress rewrite rules, you need to edit the .htaccess file and change the bold line below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.php [L] # Original line
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L] # New line
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```